# What to name these columns in my symbol table

Tags: parsing, yacc, lexical-analysis

I'm using yacc to make a symbol table for a made-up language grammar.

Column 1 will have either "variable" or "function."

Column 2 will have either "int" or "void."

I was thinking of naming one column "type" but then I wouldn't know what to call the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**identefier** for variables and functions names...

**Literal** for int or void....

hope that helps : D